# How can I identify this Nikon film camera I came across in dads estate?

Tags: nikon

I'm cleaning out my dads house and came across this analog Nikon camera in an old case.
The case looks worn but the camera and attachments look OK.
I have no idea if this is an all-in-one camera or if there a different attachments on it like filters and lenses?

I do not know anything about cameras, I've been trying to do research but don't know where to start. The serial number seems to be: `FE 3252512`.

Here are some photos of the camera and its accessories (click for larger images):

[image: camera top]
[image: camera bottom]

[image: camera front]
[image: camera with case]
[image: flash back]

[image: flash manual]
[image: flash front]

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qQ7zdNi2QaNHe7gE6 
MORE PICS

Comment: Does it have a serial number, either on the back (probably upper right side, below the film advance lever), or on the bottom?

Comment: I’m guessing this is it : FE 3252512

Comment: Don't open up the back! There might be still some film in there with possible precious photos. Instead, try to wind the film back onto its spool (feel free search and/or ask a new question about that) and only then open the back. The film can then be developed at any local photo shop.

Comment: I think there is film inside. THANKS !

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Just a little bugbear... this is not an _analog_ camera. It's a _film_ camera. Sure, music comes in "analog" and "digital" forms, but for photography, better to talk about "film" and "digital".

Comment: I was not aware of that distinction. I thought film might imply that it is a camera to record movies. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Ironically, the chemistry that takes place when film is exposed to light is more "digital" (each unit is either exposed to enough photons to react chemically or not exposed to enough photons to be transformed) than the varying analog charges that accumulate in each photosite of a digital camera.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely a Nikon SLR (single-lens reflex) camera, which takes interchangeable lenses.

I believe the camera body is a [Nikon FE](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonfeseries/fe/index.htm). Firstly, the serial number starts with "FE". =)  But also, comparing an FM to an FE (see [Nikon FM/FE/FA](http://www.nicovandijk.net/fmfefa.htm), the first picture), yours looks like the FE.

The lens has a removable filter mounted on the front, a 52mm (diameter) L1BC Sky filter. Basically, it's color-correcting UV filter, meant to slightly "warm up" or prevent a blue color cast when using daylight film on subjects in the shade (thanks to MichaelC for the clarification). There's nothing super special about the filter, those types (or the A-versions, which had a more subdued effect) were pretty commonly used on film cameras when shooting outdoors. For more about these types of filters, see:

- [What is the difference between UV and Skylight filters?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5507/11924)
- [Which filter is the more generally useful: Skylight 1A or Skylight 1B?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1318/11924)

I can't tell which lens is on the camera. It looks like it's probably a 50mm f/1.8 AI-S lens, a common and standard Nikon lens at the time. Take off the lens cap, and look at the front of the lens. It might help to unscrew the UV filter. It should say something like "NIKKOR 50mm 1:1.8" followed by a serial number, and then "Nikon" further around.

Comment: Nikkor 50mm 1:18 1864291. Thanks so much to both for helping. Really appreciate this !

Comment: Skylight filters typically have a slight orange/pink tint to them, compared to UV filters which are supposed to be neutral in the visible spectrum. The "B" filters had a stronger tint than the "A" filters did. The purpose was to be able to use daylight film when shooting subjects in the shade or on overcast days without getting a blue color cast.

Comment: @MichaelC thanks. I more-or-less edited that into the answer, plus a couple links to UV/Skylight/A-vs.-B questions.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [Nikon FE 35mm SLR manual focus camera from 1978](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Nikon_FE).

Not sure about the lens, but it seems to be a Nikkor 50mm lens with an [L1Bc filter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93933/9161) attached to it.